# Review doesn't save to a profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am able to fill out the form for the review on a user profile:

```
user_profile_reviews POST       /users/:user_id/profiles/:profile_id/reviews(.:format)                                   reviews#create
new_user_profile_review GET        /users/:user_id/profiles/:profile_id/reviews/new(.:format)                               reviews#new
```

Actually the code somehow works, as I am getting the error message, which I have defined in my Reviews Controller

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_profile
  before_action :set_review, only: :new

  def new
    @review = Review.new
  end

def create
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:profile_id])
    @review = @profile.reviews.build(review_params)
    @review.user_id = current_user.id

    if @review.save
        redirect_to user_profile_path(current_user, @profile)
    else
        redirect_to user_profile_path(current_user, @profile), notice: "Didn't save your review"
    end
end

  private

  def review_params
    params.permit(:content, :rating)
  end

def set_profile
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:profile_id])
  end

  def set_review
   @review = Review.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

After submitting I get : "Didn't save your review", so the create method works, but only half of it. Why isn't it saving? How can I correct it?

P.S. Here is my form:

```
<div class="submit-review">
  <%= form_for([@user, @profile, @review], :url => user_profile_reviews_path(@user, @profile)) do |f| %>
    <label for="review">How was your experience?</label><br>
    <%= f.label :rating %>
    <%= f.select :rating, options_for_select([["Please select one", ""], 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]) %>

    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder:"Please enter your feedback here" %>
    <%= f.submit "Submit your review", class: "btn btn-default" %> <br><br>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks that problems with permitted params.

You need to specify params key `:review`. Something like:

```
  def review_params
    params.fetch(:review, {}).permit(:rating, :content)
  end
```

Also may be some validations failed. I recommend to use rendering in your `else`, not redirecting. So you can render error messages if validations faled.